# Are 3rd party GitHub actions based on ssh keys really secure?

Tags: ssh, github-actions

I do not want to be too broad but I'm using several 3rd party GitHub actions consuming private ssh keys, such as:

- [scp-action](https://github.com/appleboy/scp-action)
- [ssh-action](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action)

In [this post](https://github.community/t/what-are-best-practices-to-deploy-your-build-artifacts-to-a-private-server/17648), I've read:

> There are a few community actions that allow you to use rsync or scp,
> but what I **totally dislike about them is that they usually run some
> privately managed Docker containers and I refuse to feed them with my
> ssh keys or even passwords.**

AFAIK, If 3rd party actions are run in private environments in GH, ssh keys shouldn't be compromised. The only risk I see is if those actions hide nasty pieces of code. But this "risk" holds for all 3rd party software dealing with privata data.

Am I right or passing ssh keys to GH actions is unsafe?

Comment: How do you define "secure" or "unsafe"?

Comment: Good point, I mean I can use ssh keys without compromising them

Comment: The difference between a `privately managed Docker container` and open source software that you can run yourself, is that you don't actually know what's running on that Docker container. It could be the open source software offered for free use, or it (could) be a modified version of the code which logs and dumps all keys uploaded to it; but in general yes, this is true for all pieces of software dealing with keys; it comes down to trust.

Comment: If you must use something like this, you can generate a new key for use specifically by the bot; then grant only the permissions required by that bot user.

Comment: Oh, so your hint is restricting somehow what such a key can do in a VPS. Right?

Comment: @MattClark regarding the `privately managed Docker container`, can't you watch into it what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible mitigation for the "I refuse to feed them with my ssh keys or even passwords" issue is rotation.

You have actions like:

- [Rotate AWS Access token stored in Github Repository secrets](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/rotate-aws-access-keys)
- [AWS Credential Rotary](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/aws-credential-rotary)
- [Secrets Sync Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/secrets-sync-action)
- ...

They are all meant to regularly rotate "secrets", in order to minimize the impact of one of them being compromised.

Comment: I see. Aren't they, in turn, a 3rd party package?

Comment: @floatingpurr They are, but you can audit/validate them and, in turn, they can manage/rotate your keys.